# "How did you do in the job interview?" vs. "How did you do on the job interview"?

Tags: prepositions

Could you tell me if the use of the prepositions *in* and *on* equally correct in the following question?

> How did you **in**/**on** the job interview?

By the way, does the question sound natural when I want to know how succesful the person was?

Comment: [Can you tell = to decipher or understand. versus: can you tell me something]

Comment: to go _____ an interview

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! And it is "go to an interview".

Comment: go to anything at all. **But** go on an interview.

Comment: Both the cited prepositions are fine (as are ***with, at,*** and possibly others). My guess is ***in*** would be the most common (followed by ***at***), but there's no need to actually *learn* to use one particular term. Since they're all "acceptable", just use the first one that comes to mind and don't worry about it.

Comment: @Lambie Sorry, but I have never heard "go on an interview". it would be "to". Also, I've equally never heard "How did you do on the job interview?" In this context I would be far more likely to expect "in".

Comment: @PrimeMover: [Here](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22went+on+an+interview%22) are plenty of written instances of *[Someone] **went on an interview***. I'm sure there would be more with ***to*** or ***for***, but they're all used.

Comment: @PrimeMover How did you do **on the interview**, **on the exam or test or quiz or questions**.  And probably a lot more. How did you do on the boat when sailing for the first time? go to an interview and go on an interview are not semantically 100% the same.

Comment: Lambie: Could you explain how "go to an interview" and "go on an interview" are different?

Comment: Simply that "go on an interview" does not sound natural, to such an extent that it sounds wrong to me.

Comment: Why not simply say "How did the job interview go?"